# Does `<remote>/<branch>` in this `git checkout` command represent a remote branch or a remote tracking branch?

Tags: git

The manpage of `git checkout` says:

> ```
> git checkout <branch>
> ```
>
> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in
>   exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

which, the manpage of `git checkout` says, invokes

```
$ git branch -f <branch> <remote>/<branch>
```

with  `-t` option to `git branch` by default (from manpage of `git branch`)

> ```
> -t
> ```
>
> When creating a new branch, set up  `branch.<branch>.remote`  and  `branch.<branch>.merge` configuration entries to mark the start-point branch as "upstream" from the new branch.

What does `<remote>/<branch>` in the equivalent `git checkout` command and in the `git branch` command represent?

1. Since the `git branch` command sets up  `branch.<branch>.remote`  and  `branch.<branch>.merge` to be a remote repository and a remote branch, does `<remote>/<branch>`  represent the remote branch (the upstream branch to-be)?
2. Since the `git branch` command create a new local branch starting from `<remote>/<branch>`, does `<remote>/<branch>`represent the remote tracking branch?

Answer (score 5):

`git help revisions` will tell you how a refname is interpreted.

For reference,

> `<refname>`, e.g. `master`, `heads/master`, `refs/heads/master`
>          A symbolic ref name. E.g.  master typically means the commit object referenced by refs/heads/master. If
>          you happen to have both heads/master and tags/master, you can explicitly say heads/master to tell Git
>          which one you mean. When ambiguous, a  is disambiguated by taking the first match in the
>          following rules:
>
> 1. If $GIT_DIR/<refname> exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, MERGE_HEAD and CHERRY_PICK_HEAD);
> 2. otherwise, refs/<refname> if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, refs/tags/<refname> if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, refs/heads/<refname> if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname> if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD if it exists.
>
>    `HEAD` names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.  FETCH_HEAD records the
>      branch which you fetched from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation.  ORIG_HEAD is
>      created by commands that move your HEAD in a drastic way, to record the position of the HEAD before
>      their operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch back to the state before you ran
>      them.  MERGE_HEAD records the commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run git
>      merge.  CHERRY_PICK_HEAD records the commit which you are cherry-picking when you run git
>      cherry-pick.
>
>    Note that any of the refs/* cases above may come either from the $GIT_DIR/refs directory or from the
>      $GIT_DIR/packed-refs file. While the ref name encoding is unspecified, UTF-8 is preferred as some
>      output processing may assume ref names in UTF-8.
>
>    `@`
>             @ alone is a shortcut for HEAD.

So when you say `origin/master` and Git's looking for something in the repo there, it'll search according to that list and unless you've taken to punning your remote names with branch or tag prefixes it'll find the remote-tracking ref `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

(note that there are a lot of handy ways to refer to this or that set of revisions in Git, see the docs).

Comment: Thanks. If `origin/master` represents a remote tracking branch, how can it be used as the upstream branch of a local branch?

Comment: All refs are local. Any correspondence with refnames in another repo is entirely a matter of convenience and convention.  By the above rules `origin/master` will match `refs/remotes/origin/master`, a local ref (all refs are local) updated, by convention, when `git fetch` retrieves history from other repos.  What exactly `git fetch` does is configurable and selectable, the factory defaults are widely applicable but the knobs can all be occasionally put to good use.

Answer (score 4):

See [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165482/1256452) for how things work normally, which is how they *should* work.

There's a nasty little wrinkle here if you configure your `remote.origin.fetch` to an unusual set of strings, though.  Both `git fetch` and `git checkout`—well, anything that uses a branch's upstream, really—wind up using a data structure that Git calls a *refmap*.  **Note that there is never, as far as I can tell, any good reason to *do* what I am about to describe.**  But *Git* does it (based on the user's configuration), so we must be aware of its behavior if we wish to program Git correctly when writing our own code to *use* Git configurations.

Let's say, for example, that you configure `remote.origin.fetch` this way:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/weird_develop
```

Now when you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

you'll get their `refs/heads/master` and record it in your own repository as `refs/remotes/origin/master`, quite normally.  But you'll treat their `refs/heads/develop` *differently*, creating or updating your own `refs/remotes/origin/weird_develop` in your own repository.

Hence, your remote-tracking branches that remember *their* `master` and `develop` are called `origin/master` and `origin/weird_develop` (for short) in *your* repository, even though they are called `master` and `develop` in *their* repository.

Now suppose you'd like to create your own branch named `develop`.  If you were using *sane* `fetch =` configurations, its upstream setting—what `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref develop@{upstream}` prints—would be `origin/develop`.  But for some (not-sane?) reason, you've configured this rather bizarre set of `fetch =` settings, so running `git fetch` creates or updates one weirded remote-tracking name.

**Despite the weird remote-tracking names, the *branch* configurations will use the actual branch names on the upstream.**  That is, inspecting `.git/config` after doing:

```
git checkout --track develop origin/weird_develop
```

you will see:

```
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
```

The question you should ask is: *How did Git put `refs/heads/develop` into this entry, when my upstream setting is `origin/weird_develop`?*

The answer is that Git has built this *refmap* thing, that says that *their* (origin's) `refs/heads/develop` is your `refs/remotes/origin/weird_develop`.  This refmap goes both ways: Git can either look up their `refs/heads/develop` to find your remote-tracking name, or Git can look up your `refs/remotes/origin/weird_develop` to find origin's branch name.

For all this to work, the refmap constructed from the `fetch =` setting must not change dynamically.  That is, if you edit your `.git/config` file and alter the `fetch` lines semi-randomly, your own Git will start to behave oddly, once the constructed refmap no longer matches reality, or if you create maps that are not proper bijections.<sup>1</sup>

---

By *bijection* here, I mean that every name that you do copy from the remote should map to a unique remote-tracking name in your own repository, and this should cover the entire set of remote-tracking names in your repository.  The simple case of `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` obviously meets this criterion.  However, if you say, for instance:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/extra_master
```

you've created a *multivalued function* in the origin-to-local-repository direction, since `master` must be copied to *two* names, and a surjective mapping in the reverse direction, since your `origin/master` and `origin/extra_master` both map to their `master`.  Git will stop with various errors for these cases.

Comment: Note that this is true of the config entry—it's for the actual remote branch name, not the local ref it maps to—but not true of the command line arguments OP asked about.  The command line arguments still use the local refnames.

Comment: By the way, one common use for the refmap is `+refs/*:refs/*` for a mirror clone.